# Tooltip with own event listeners

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip, dom-events

Sorry if this is partially duplicate, couldn't find any satisfactory answer.

I have a d3 graph that consists of a line with points. My points have events that make a tooltip appear/disappear, see below:

```
var div = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

var points = g.selectAll(".point")
    .data(data).enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "point")
    .on('mouseover', function(d, i) {

        var xPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('x')) + margin.left
        var yPos = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr('y')) + margin.top - 20

        div.interrupt();
        div
            .style("left", xPos + 'px')
            .style("top", yPos + 'px')
            .style('opacity', 0.9);

        div.html('<p><strong>Upper Text</strong></p><p>Lower Text</p>');
    })
    .on('mouseout', function(d, i) {
        div
            .transition().delay(1000)
            .style("opacity", 0);
    });
```

This works fine: a tooltip appears close to my point when I hover over it, and disappears 1 second after I move the cursor off it.

**What I want:** to interrupt the tooltip fadeaway if I hover over the tooltip itself, then make it disappear if I move the cursor away from it.

(i.e. if the tooltip has text and a link, I want the user to be able to move the cursor from the point to the tooltip and then keep the tooltip visible for as long as the cursor is over it)

I tried this:

```
var div = d3.select("body")
   .append("div")
   .attr("class", "tooltip")
   .style("opacity", 0)
   // on mouseover, interrupt the transition triggered when I moved
   // the cursor away from the point and over the tooltip
   .on('mouseover', function() {
       d3.select(this)
           .interrupt();
   })
   // on mouseout, quickly fade the tooltip away
   .on('mouseout', function() {
       d3.select(this)
           .transition().duration(100)
           .style("opacity", 0.0);
   });
```

But it appears that the tooltip doesn't contain the event listeners I tried to bind to it.

**My question is:** How do I add the event listeners to the tooltip, so that it will stay visible if I move the cursor from the point to the tooltip?

Comment: Your solution is working for me. Look at this demo I just created: https://jsfiddle.net/ouosssp2/

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Your comment helped me find the cause, which I posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Gerardo, the code actually works. The reason why I thought it didn't is because I had my css as follows:

```
.tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

The `pointer-events: none` was obviously disabling all DOM events in the tooltip. Removing this line resolved my issue.